# Observable.Create doesn't work and Observable.ToEnumerable blocks indefinitely

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, .net-4.5, system.reactive

Why the code below doesn't work?

```
var observable = Observable.Create<int>(o => new Action(() =>
{
    o.OnNext(0);
    o.OnCompleted();
}));

foreach (var item in observable.ToEnumerable()) // <-- Here blocks
{
    // Never get here
}
```

The below doesn't work neither:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var item in observable.ToEnumerable()) // <-- Still blocks
    {
        // Never get here
    }
}).Wait();
```

Interestingly, the Generate method works as expected:

```
var observable = Observable.Generate(0, i => i < 1, i => i + 1, i => i);

foreach (var item in observable.ToEnumerable())
{
    // Is ok
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
var observable = Observable.Create<int>(o => new Action(() =>
{
    o.OnNext(0);
    o.OnCompleted();
}));
```

You meant to provide a function that calls `OnNext` upon subscription. However, you've *inadvertently* called the wrong overload of `Observable.Create` and provided it with a function which does nothing but create an action (which will be called upon *disposal* of the subscription). So (by mistake), you're trying to call `OnNext` only when the subscription is disposed.

This is what you meant to do:

```
var observable = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
{
    o.OnNext(0);
    o.OnCompleted();

    return () => Console.WriteLine("Disposed!"); // this will be called when 
                                                  // subscription is disposed
});
```

Or this:

```
var observable = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
{
    o.OnNext(0);
    o.OnCompleted();

    return Disposable.Empty; // using System.Reactive.Disposables;
});
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand that correctly. The action doesn't define _yielding_ but _disposing_. Therefore `ToEnumerable` blocks because `OnCompleted` have never occurred and also my action acting as dispose method is waiting for `OnCompleted` and thus is never invoked too.

Comment: Correct, with a slight correction that `ToEnumerable` blocks until `OnNext`, not until `OnCompleted`.